# How to reverse search for a property in an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, reverse

How do you reverse lookup an object's attribute in JavaScript?

For example, say I have an object:

```js
var price = {
  water: '$1.00',
  beer: '$30.00',
  xbox: '$500.00'
}
```

Typing in `price.water` would return `'$1.00'`. But to find the ITEM by the PRICE, instead of the price by the item, I would like to type `fnToFindItemByPrice('$1.00')`, and get `'water'`.

Comment: Can you have two or more item prices that are the same? eg: `soda: "$1.00"`. If so, are you expecting an array as your output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
var price = {
  water: '$1.00',
  beer: '$30.00',
  xbox: '$500.00'
}


function findItemByPrice(item){
  return Object.keys(price).find(e => price[e] == item)
}

console.log(findItemByPrice('$1.00'))
```

If you have more than one property with the value, you can use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var price = {
  water: '$1.00',
  beer: '$30.00',
  xbox: '$500.00',
  water2: '$1.00',
}


function findItemByPrice(item){
  return Object.keys(price).filter(e => price[e] == item)
}

console.log(findItemByPrice('$1.00'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that values are not unique, unlike keys.

```js
var price = {
  water: '$1.00',
  beer: '$30.00',
  coffee: '$1.00',
  xbox: '$500.00'
};

var one_dollar = [];
for (let k in price) {
  if (price[k] === '$1.00') {
    one_dollar.push(k);
  }
}

console.log(one_dollar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and a [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop. Your code would look like this:

```js
const price = {
    water: '$1.00',
    beer: '$30.00',
    xbox: '$500.00'
}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(price)) {
    if (value === '$1.00') {
        console.log(key);
    }
}
```

If you are going to have more than 1 value with `$1.00` like [@mister wtf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6316468/mister-wtf) said, then you have to use [`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to get this. See an example of this below:

```js
let results = [];
let result;
const price = {
    water: '$1.00',
    sparklingWater: '$1.00',
    beer: '$30.00',
    xbox: '$500.00'
}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(price)) {
    if (value === '$1.00') {
        results.push(key);
    }
}

if (results.length < 2) {
    result = results[0];
} else {
    result = results;
}

console.log(result);
```

**Hoped this helped!**

Answer (score 0):

```js
const f_reverse = obj => Object.entries(obj).reduce((r,[k,v])=>(r[v]=k,r),{})

const price = 
  { water : '$1.00'
  , beer  : '$30.00'
  , xbox  : '$500.00'
  } 
const fruits =
  { apples  : 'normandy'
  , pears   : 'italy'
  , bananas : 'gabon'
  , oranges : 'california' 
  }  
const priceRev = f_reverse(price)
const products = f_reverse(fruits)

console.log( priceRev['$1.00'] )    // -> water
console.log( products.california )  // -> oranges
```

In case of multiple keys with the same value:

```js
const f_reverse = obj => Object.entries(obj).reduce((r,[k,v])=>
    {
    if (!r.hasOwnProperty(v))       r[v] = k
    else if (!Array.isArray(r[v]))  r[v] = [ r[v], k ]
    else                            r[v].push(k)
    return r
    },{})

const price = 
  { water : '$1.00'
  , beer  : '$30.00'
  , xbox  : '$500.00'
  , tacos : '$1.00'
  , glub  : '$1.00'
  } 
  
const priceRev = f_reverse(price)

console.log('$1.00->', priceRev['$1.00'])     // ['water','tacos','glub']
console.log('$500.00->', priceRev['$500.00']) //  'xbox'
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```

For an array back:

(In case of use by chaining plan to use a [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).)

```js
const f_reverse = obj =>
  Object.entries(obj).reduce((r,[k,v])=>(r[v]??=[],r[v].push(k),r),{})

const price = 
  { water : '$1.00'
  , beer  : '$30.00'
  , xbox  : '$500.00'
  , tacos : '$1.00'
  , glub  : '$1.00'
  } 
  
const priceRev = f_reverse(price)

console.log('$1.00->', priceRev['$1.00'])     // ['water','tacos','glub']
console.log('$500.00->', priceRev['$500.00']) // ['xbox']
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```